# In CPLEX, how to find a variable in the model is in the basis or not?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, cplex, basis

I am looking for a simple way to obtain the list of base variables a LP problem with CPLEX, or a way to indicate a variable is in basis or not?

Actually, I am working on a column generation algorithm. After solving the Restricted Master Problem, the new column becomes 0. How can check the new variable is 0 but in basis, i.e., degeneracy, or it is not in basis and there is an error in my implementation?

Comment: You are probably looking for `GetBasisStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use getBasisStatuses in C++

> This method puts the basis status of each variable in var into the
> corresponding element of the array cstat, and it puts the status of
> each row in con (an array of ranges or constraints)into the
> corresponding element of the array rstat.Arrays rstat and cstat are
> resizedaccordingly.